# Python pymysql cant accept special characters in the password string, How to bypass this?

Tags: python, mysql, special-characters, pymysql

I have code to read the credentials from an external config file,

```
   configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
   configFilePath = r'docs/credentials.cfg'
   configParser.read(configFilePath)
```

AnD

```
   User = configParser.get('your-config', 'user')
   Pswd = configParser.get('your-config','pswd')
   Host = configParser.get('your-config','hostdps')
   db = pymysql.connect(host=Host, user=User, password=Pswd, db='xyz', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,local_infile=True)
```

The password contains special characters like : #?f8h!3, How to make connect statement understand these chars.?

I have already tried adding backslashes, passing it in connect string, not sure how to get this?

Comment: you have to use `UTF8`

Comment: I am already using UTF8 as charset?

Comment: It would be important to check which encoding is used in the mysql database. It should be the same as the one you use in the connect statement I guess

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was adding quotes before the start of password string in the config file.

I was using : configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser() so, it was treating " as part of the password.

Quite silly.